# Get last date of the month for the next occuring month

Tags: php, mysql, date

Is it possible to get the last date of the month for the next 12 months.

for example. (YYYY-MM-DD)

full year:

```
today is:      2014-05-09 
get 1st month: 2014-06-09
get 2nd month: 2014-07-09
get 3rd month: 2014-08-09
get 4th month: 2014-09-09
get 5th month: 2014-10-09
get 6th month: 2014-11-09
get 7th month: 2014-12-09
get 8th month: 2015-01-09
get 9th month: 2015-02-09
get 10th month: 2015-03-09
get 11th month: 2015-04-09
get 12th month: 2015-05-09
```

half year:

```
today is:      2014-05-29 
get 1st month: 2014-06-29
get 2nd month: 2014-07-29
get 3rd month: 2014-08-29
get 4th month: 2014-09-29
get 5th month: 2014-10-29
get 6th month: 2014-11-29
get 7th month: 2014-12-29
get 8th month: 2015-01-29
**get 9th month: 2015-02-28**
get 10th month: 2015-03-29
get 11th month: 2015-04-29
get 12th month: 2015-05-29
```

thank you

Comment: check here [link](http://www.sourcecodemart.com/first-and-last-day-of-month-in-php/)

Comment: what should be displayed if `today is 2014-05-31`?

Comment: I'm confused. You say you want the last date of the month but your example shows the 9th? Also, why would looping prevent you from assigning variables?

Comment: "without looping in the code because I want to assigned variable for it" --- what does it mean?

Comment: @MarkM He may want to create 12 variables for store each value (Like $month1, $month2 etc. ). While it is possible through array in loop, but he may not preferring array.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj Variable variables: `${"month{$i}"}`. `extract($arr)` would also do it.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, I have same thing in my mind, If OP prefer it.

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion I just edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the last day of the month you can use :

```
<?php
$date = time();
$full_year = array();
for($idx = 1 ; $idx <= 12 ; $idx++) {
    $tmp = strtotime("last day of next month",$date);
    $full_year[] = date("Y-m-d",$tmp);
    $date = $tmp;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($full_year);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

$full_year variable will contain the date for each month (starting from 0 for next month and ending with 11) (you can use any of the dates like $full_year[0]...$full_year[11])

If you want the result stored in full_year to be the same as the example you gave (which is not the last day of the month, but simply 1 month from today), you can use :

```
<?php
$date = time();
$full_year = array();
for($idx = 1 ; $idx <= 12 ; $idx++) {
    $tmp = strtotime("next month",$date);
    $full_year[] = date("Y-m-d",$tmp);
    $date = $tmp;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($full_year);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: can you vote up my question? because I think it is helpful for future developers. thank you

Answer (score 2):

here's a sample code of the idea, this gets the total number of days in a month, which, equals to the last date of the month.

```
$month = 1;
$year = 2014;
echo date('t',mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
```

and what's the problem of looping? you could still assign values in it as long as you do it right.
edit your question and include the part you assign variables and maybe everyone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can increment manually, like this...

```
$interval="+1 month";
$date=date("Y-m-d");
$month1=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($interval, $date));
$month2=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($interval, $month1));
$month3=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($interval, $month2));

... etc
```

But I am sure you can see how that could get tedious.

I would recommend looping, but storing your variables in an array (a construct with which you can store more than one variable... Like so:

```
$interval="+1 month";
$months=array();
$date=date("Y-m-d");
array_push($months, date("Y-m-d", strtotime($interval, $date))); //create the first array element, so that we don't have to check it's existence and waste time in the loop

for ($i=1; $i<12; $i++) 
{
    array_push($months, date("Y-m-d", strtotime($interval, $months[i-1])));
}
```

I haven't tested this yet but it should work more or less fine without much modification:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to do this without looping. Tanatos has posted a great answer on how to do this with a loop. But because you said you didn't want to do it this way (for whatever reason), here is the manual alternative:

```
$stamp = "last day of next month"; 
//$stamp = "+1 month"; // Use this if you want what is in your example
$month1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, time()));
$month2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month1)));
$month3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month2)));
$month4 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month3)));
$month5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month4)));
$month6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month5)));
$month7 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month6)));
$month8 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month7)));
$month9 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month8)));
$month10 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month9)));
$month11 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month10)));
$month12 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stamp, strtotime($month11)));
```